# If $G$ is abelian then $\phi_n$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am working on the following question.

> Let G be a group and let $n$ be any integer. For each integer $n$ define the map $\phi_n:G \rightarrow G$ by $\phi_n(a)=a^n$ for every element $a$ in the group. Prove that if $G$ is abelian then $\phi_n$ is a homomorphism for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Note**: I have seen similar proofs on this forum for related questions when $n=2$.

My work thus far is:

Let $a,b \in G$. Consider $\phi_n(ab)=(ab)^n=\underbrace{ab \cdot ab \cdot ab \cdots ab}_{n}=\underbrace{a \cdot a \cdots a}_{n} \cdot \underbrace{b \cdot b \cdots b}_{n}=a^n \cdot b^n=\phi_n(a) \phi_n(b)$. Where $(ab)^n=a^n  b^n$ is true since $G$ is abelian.

This seems straightforward except I feel as though more steps are needed to explain why $\underbrace{ab \cdot ab \cdot ab \cdots ab}_{n}=\underbrace{a \cdot a \cdots a}_{n} \cdot \underbrace{b \cdot b \cdots b}_{n}$ is true other than by saying because $G$ is abelian.

Thank you.

Comment: If you feel more is needed, you can proceed by induction.  It's easy if $n=1$, if you assume it for $n-1$ then $(ab)^n=ab(ab)^{n-1}=aba^{n-1}b^{n-1}$ and now you are just looking at a simple rearrangement.

Comment: I would say that at the level you are at, you probably don't need to say any more. As lulu said, you are technically using induction, but it is "obvious" enough that I can't imagine a professor harping on it. It is good that you are thinking about these things though.

Comment: @Lulu Thank you, the induction argument helps me very much.

Comment: @ElliotG Your comment might depend on the institution.  Sometimes, abstract algebra is a first proof class and this proof might be asking to show the ability to apply induction formally to a problem in group theory.

Comment: Conversely, if $\phi_2$ or $\phi_{-1}$ is a homomorphism, then $G$ is abelian.